# PHP calling Bash-script

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server, script, php

I have real problems getting this PHP-script "search.php" that is called from a "form.htm" to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
   $old_path = getcwd();
   chdir('/var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/');
   $term1 = $_POST['query1'];
   $argument1 = $_GET['$term1'];
   $term2 = $_POST['query2'];
   $argument2 = $_GET['$term2'];
   echo $nu_kor_vi1;
   $outcome = shell_exec("sokare $argument1 $argument2");
   chdir($old_path);
   echo "<pre>$outcome</pre>";
?>
```

The script is calling a Bash-script **"sokare"** that is executable systemwide and residning in **"/usr/local/bin"**. The variables **$argument1** and **$argument2** are passed from the **"form.htm"** via **$term1 = $_POST['query1'];** and **$term2 = $_POST['query2'];** . The Bash-script looks like this. It is supposed to search any PDF-files residing in **"/var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/"** for pages containing both searchwords.

```
#!/bin/bash

pdfgrep -Hn $1 /var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/*.pdf | cut -f1,2 -d':' > /tmp/sok1.tmp
pdfgrep -Hn $2 /var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/*.pdf | cut -f1,2 -d':' > /tmp/sok2.tmp
grep -f /tmp/sok1.tmp /tmp/sok2.tmp

exit 0
```

I keep on getting this error in **"/var/log/apache2/error.log"** : PHP Notice:  Undefined index: $term2 in /var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/search.php on line 7, referer: http://localhost/SOKHJALPMEDEL/form.htm

Any help clearing my mess up is beautiful:-)

/Paul

Comment: A quick thought is i'd var_dump() $_POST, as it looks like $term2 is empty.

Comment: Please be aware that there are serious security risks with this code! Anyone would be able to arbitrarily read files and execute commands on your system. You should not directly pass arguments from the client (GET and POST) to the command line, but use regular expressions or some other mechanism to check if they arguments the clients sends make sense. (anyone who uses a `;` in the GET will be able to execute other commands), see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection (Example 6)

Comment: It seems like the basic problem is how to make a PHP-variable become a combination of two other PHP-variables, something like "var3 = var1 && var2", so that "var3" could be used as arguments to the script "sokare $1 $2" where "var3" contains "$1", then a space, followed by "$2".

Comment: I tried to make a variable equal to "echo" something, such as $var3 = exec("echo $var1 $var2"); , but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working script doing what I wanted:

```
<?php
   $old_path = getcwd();
   chdir('/var/www/html/SOKHJALPMEDEL/');
   $term1 = $_POST['query1'];
   $term2 = $_POST['query2'];
   ob_start();
   echo "{$term1} {$term2}";
   $var = ob_get_clean();
   $outcome = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/sokare $var");
   chdir($old_path);
   echo "<pre>$outcome</pre>";
?>
```

The key to get the functionality I was looking for is this piece of code:

```
ob_start();
echo "{$term1} {$term2}";
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

This creates the variable $var which is used as the argument $1 and $2 used by the Bash-script.

/Paul

Comment: Please tell us why you made the changes that you did, it helps future readers understand the solution better.

Comment: I will try. ob_start();
   echo "{$term1} {$term2}";
   $var = ob_get_clean();

Comment: please edit your answer to motivate the changes

Comment: Is there any reason why `$var = "{$term1} {$term2}"` would not work? Besides that it's still some dangerous piece of code as you're still not checking the contents. Beware that you could also omit `query1` or `query2` and you would get an error similar to the one you had in your initial post.

Comment: Seth, you are correct; $var = "{$term1} {$term2}" does work. I'm not a PHP guru. I'm just happy I had it working:-)